# Converting and/or enforcing an Ascii Character Set in Informix database from 819 or ISO Latin 1

Tags: migration, character-set, instance, informix, environment-variables

Overview: In Informix is it possible to enforce `ASCII` for a database or instance.

Details: I am trying to enforce `ASCII` in an instance of informix for a while. This is to help have a smooth transition between char sets: `ISO Latin-1 (819)` and `UTF8`. I would like this to be done by cleansing my current data of non `ASCII` characters and then exporting the data from the databases. These steps have already been done.

Then setting the character set to enforce `ASCII`. However I cannot find a character set that I can use that my instance allows me to change the db_locale too. My current db_locale is default aka `ISO Latin 1` or `819`. After I figure out the character set. I believe that I can figure out the rest. It should be just importing the data to a new database with the db_locale set to an `ASCII` char set.

Is this possible? I am also open to other ways of setting or enforcing `ASCII` at the database level.

Comment: I don't think there's a 'strict ASCII' character set in Informix, nor an easy way to enforce the rule that character columns should not contain any characters with the 8th bit set.  In principle, a GLS character set for that could be developed and used — it wouldn't be very hard.  It isn't trivial, either, though.

Comment: When the time comes to migrate, you could export the accented data, then use the `iconv` program to convert from 8859-1 to UTF8.

Comment: Where could I find instructions or examples of how to create a GLS character set? @JonathanLeffler

Comment: I started an enquirer yesterday but the person who knows best is under deadline pressure this week.  Intense, ridiculous deadline pressure.